# What is an execution frame?

Tags: c#, stack, callstack

In C#, what is an execution frame (also related to this I have heard of activation frame).
 IIRC it is a slot where method parameters go but cannot remember all of the details.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

"Execution frame" is a term that is used in interpreted languages, Python in particular.  That's a very different execution model from C#.  The closest equivalent is a scope block in a C# method, a chunk of code that is is bracketed with curly braces.  Although a Python execution frame could also extend to the body of a function, now it's equivalent to a stack frame in C#.  Which is another term for an activation frame.

The C# compiler recognizes declarations that are local to a scope block in C#.  The runtime doesn't, it only recognizes a stack frame that's active for the life of the entire method.  The difference is trivially papered-over by the compiler by simply declaring the sum of all local variables in all scope blocks as the activation frame.  That's a luxury that a Python interpreter cannot afford.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're referring to a stack frame - in which case the answer is not specific to C# or indeed to any particular language, but rather to the platform that your program is executing on. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) on the [Call Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack):

> A call stack is composed of stack
>   frames (sometimes called activation
>   records). These are machine dependent
>   data structures containing subroutine
>   state information. Each stack frame
>   corresponds to a call to a subroutine
>   which has not yet terminated with a
>   return.

See also [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap/80113#80113) for an excellent description of the stack, including stack frames.

Comment: So is an execution frame the same as a stack frame? I've seen the terms used seperately but I mean the exec frame (I'm aware of stack frame).

Comment: Yes, I believe the terms are synonymous in general, and at least in the context of C#.

Comment: See the other answer from @nobugz - it appears that "Execution Frame" can have different meaning in the context of some other languages, especially Python.